# String Image Url set in imageview Android

Tags: android, imageview

I Need a help for My First develop android app. I want to set a image with the help of url in my **ImageView** which is coming from google Api. I have a listView in Which the data are coming from google apis. in **Listview**, I implement a image with the help of picasso android libruary. I am using a fragment when the user click on each list item from listView. On CLick of listItem I am opening a fragment on Which I need To display a data of list Item.

For ListView, I am using a userDefined List in which the images are of type

In DetailFragment where I want to display the details I am using the below Source Code.

```
@Override
    public void findViewById() {
        foodtitle=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.detail_foodtext);
        foodsubtitle=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.detail_foodsubtext);
        foodresImage=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.detail_image_left);
        foodaddress=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.detail_foodaddress);

    Bundle b=getArguments();
    b.getString("ItemName");
    b.getString("ItemSubItem");
    b.getInt("ItemImage");
    b.getString("ItemAddress");
    foodtitle.setText(b.getString("ItemName"));
    foodsubtitle.setText(b.getString("ItemSubItem"));
    foodresImage.setImageResource(b.getInt("ItemImage"));
    foodaddress.setText(b.getString("ItemAddress"));
 }
```

on This place

```
foodresImage.setImageResource(b.getInt("ItemImage"));
```

I want my Image which is one imageView in detail Fragment.

Comment: If you want to load image by url, let's try Picasso or Glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `Picasso` then you should use it like:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(fb.getString("ItemImage")).into(foodresImage);
```

You are using `fb.getInt()` in your `setImageResource` and you are getting a `string` from the Google API. You cannot convert the link to an int resource.